# Multi-line Scss indentation in WebStorm

Tags: sass, webstorm, stylelint

Does anyone know of a way to get WebStorm to indent following the default Stylelint guidelines properly?

Specifically, I'm having an issue with scss indentation of transforms with multiple properties. The recommended pattern is:

```
.class-name {
  transition:
    transform 100ms ease-out,
    opacity 10ms linear 90ms;
}
```

However, I can't get WebStorm to support this at all. When I auto-indent my code it will turn the above into:

```
.class-name {
  transition: transform 100ms ease-out,
  opacity  10ms linear 90ms;
}
```

Any help on this would be great. For reference, I'm currently using the following version of WebStorm:

```
WebStorm 2016.3
Build #WS-163.7743.13, built on November 8, 2016
```